# Lifespan of particles

Tags: particle-detectors, elementary-particles

After reading a very informative tutorial on elementary particles physics over at http://www.particleadventure.org, I have a question I can't figure out.

I understand the need to accelerate a particle to high energy level, as it allows to view "smaller" stuff when you bombard a target with it. But the resulting particles that fly out into detectors have very short life as they quickly decay. Does it mean that those particles don't occur in nature because they decay very rapidly? And if so, what is the usefulness of studying those particles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What comes out of those collisions can tell us a lot about what started out. The particles coming out weren't there to being with, they were produced by the violent collisions. What comes out, as well as its energy, tells us information about the scattering cross sections. These cross sections get calculated from models with free parameters, and we use the measured cross sections to fit those parameters. Large, exotic particles come from rare events, which means we don't know those parameters very well, or they may not even be modeled by an existing model at all. The later is what physicists mean when they talk about "Beyond Standard Model physics", things with cross sections the Standard Model does not predict.

The particles get created by the energy of the collision, and the rate that it gets created tells us things about our parameters. Just because it doesn't exist in free space for very long doesn't mean it doesn't exist at all. The Higgs field, in particular, exists everywhere. What we interpret as the Higgs boson is an excitation of that field above its ground state. When it decays back to the ground state, what we see tells us about how strongly or weakly the Higgs field is coupled to the fields of the particles it produces.

You can't measure a ground state, just transitions. A particle is an excitation of a field. Some fields have zero average in a vacuum (electrons for example). The Higgs is special because it has a non-zero average in a vacuum, but until we could excite the field and watch it decay, we couldn't study anything about it. Now we can.

Comment: But if the particles coming out weren't there to begin with, what good does it do us? For instance, the Higgs boson is supposedly tied to matter having mass. But if it only exists for a few nanoseconds after a collision, how does it still work outside of accelerator?

Comment: It gets created by the energy of the collision, and the rate that it gets created tells us things about our parameters. Just because it doesn't exist in free space for very long doesn't mean it doesn't exist at all. The Higgs field, in particular, exists everywhere. What we interpret as the Higgs boson is an excitation of that field above its ground state. When it decays back to the ground state, what we see tells us about how strongly or weakly the Higgs field is coupled to the fields of the particles it produces.

Comment: Ah, I see. So when a physicist says "a new particle is created", they don't literally mean it, just that we can now observe the particle (and we couldn't observe it in its ground state)?

Comment: More or less, yes. You can't measure a ground state, just transitions. A particle is an excitation of a field. Some fields have zero average in a vacuum (electrons for example). The Higgs is special because it has a non-zero average in a vacuum, but until we could excite the field and watch it decay, we couldn't study anything about it. Now we can.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'll update your answer with content of your comments and mark it accepted.